# Using fabric8 docker-maven-plugin to build images on a remote docker daemon

Tags: maven, docker, gitlab-ci, docker-maven-plugin

I'm attempting to use fabric8's `docker-maven-plugin` to build docker images within my gitlab ci pipeline.

### Background:

My image build stage in `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like:

```
build_image:
  stage: build
  image: $JAVA_IMAGE
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: docker-build
  script:
    - ./mvnw docker:build
  allow_failure: true
  except: *nobuild
  tags:
    - autoscaler
```

My pom has

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.30.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- the hostname should be the same as the service alias specified in the gitlab ci file-->
        <dockerHost>tcp://docker-build:2375</dockerHost>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>my-image</name>
                <build>
                    <contextDir>${project.basedir}/path/where/Dockerfile/lives</contextDir>
                    <filter>false</filter>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>latest</tag>
                        <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    </tags>
                </build>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And my Dockerfile contains

```
COPY ./some/directory/ /destination/path/within/image
```

But the build fails with the error

```
41014 [ERROR] DOCKER> Unable to build image [my-image] : "COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder785340074/some/directory/: no such file or directory"  ["COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder785340074/some/directory/: no such file or directory" ]
```

### Question:

The problem seems to be that maven, within the container built from `$JAVA_IMAGE`, is using the `docker:dind` container's docker daemon (at `tcp://docker-build:2375`) to build `my-image` (as intended), but the `docker:dind` container does not have access to the files on the `$JAVA_IMAGE` container at `./some/directory/`. Is there a way to give it access to those files, or to copy those files onto the `docker:dind` container? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do (while maintaining the separation between the service image `docker:dind` and the build image `$JAVA_IMAGE`)?

Comment: May be the descriptions found here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html are helpfull. They describe how to set a mount-point for the  dind container.